# Returning clean, timezone free dates in JS

Tags: javascript, date

I'm building an app with Knockout that works with a large number of dates, at various stages. Of course, they all have this nonsense slapped on the end:

```
T05:00:00.000Z
```

Is there a tidy way to have all the dates be simple Year-month-day, *without* resorting to making my own concatenations? I know I can do this:

```
getYear() . getMonth() + 1 . getDate()
```

...but that would get unwieldy in my case, given the fact that there are several places in my code that are spitting out dates

Is there some clean function that will just give me a simple date? Maybe some kind of tweak to the Date prototype?

I should mention, that since this is a Knockout app, the dates are stored inside observables. The issue is making sure that when I save the date to JSON, the dates are formatted more cleanly.

Comment: "a whack of dates" ... what does that mean?

Comment: Lots. Many. Tons. A bunch. Various places in my app are returning dates.

Answer (score 3):

This is where the concept of abstractions really comes into play.  Since you're really only dealing with 3 simple functions that you don't want to repeat over and over again in your code, just write one helper function and then use that in your code:

```
function getFormattedDate() {
    return getYear() + '.' + getMonth() + 1 + '.' + getDate();
}
```

Then whenever you need the date, run:

```
var d = getFormattedDate();
```

or

```
alert(getFormattedDate());
```

or

```
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "Today's date is " + getFormattedDate();
```

To keep your getFormattedDate function out of the global scope, and be sure you don't conflict with another implementation of getFormattedDate, use namespacing:

```
var myUtils = {
    getFormattedDate: function() {
        return getYear() + '.' + getMonth() + 1 + '.' + getDate();
    }
};
```

then invoke it as:

```
alert( myUtils.getFormattedDate() );
```

Comment: Thanks man. I should have mentioned, this is an app I'm building in Knockout, and the dates are stored in observables. The issue is making sure that when I save the date to JSON, the dates are formatted more cleanly.

Comment: Couldn't have said it any better

Comment: @BenjaminAllison - This should still work for you. Regular JavaScript should, in theory, work just fine with knockout. I am not familiar with knockout, but there may be some "best practice" or alternative method of writing your own functions. I'll update this question with how I personally would define that function.

Comment: Something is missing. `getYear() . getMonth() + 1 . getDate();` isn't really valid and would throw an error written that way

Comment: @SeanMC - It looks like PHP concatenations. As this was 10 years ago, I honestly cannot recall why both the question asker and myself wrote it like this. Instead, one possible answer is `return getYear() + ( getMonth() + 1) + getDate();`